# create two interpolated grids from two sets of xyz points and calculate difference using python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, surface

I'm trying to accomplish something similar. But trying to calculate difference between two interpolated grids. The grids are of different shapes, so cannot use np.subtract to calculate the difference. Any help on how to calculate the difference?

```
#create two interpolated grids from two set of xyz points and calculate difference  
ixx = np.array(self.ix)
    iyy = np.array(self.iy)
    izz = np.array(self.iz)

    iminx = min(ixx.flat)
    imaxx = max(ixx.flat)
    iminy = min(iyy.flat)
    imaxy = max(iyy.flat)

    # post surface - get extents
    pxx = np.array(self.px)
    pyy = np.array(self.py)
    pzz = np.array(self.pz)

    pminx = min(pxx.flat)
    pmaxx = max(pxx.flat)
    pminy = min(pyy.flat)
    pmaxy = max(pyy.flat)

    ixi = np.arange(iminx, imaxx, self.cellsize)
    iyi = np.arange(iminy, imaxy, self.cellsize)
    iX,iY = np.meshgrid(ixi,iyi)
    iextent = (min(ixi), max(ixi), min(iyi), max(iyi))

    pxi = np.arange(pminx, pmaxx, self.cellsize)
    pyi = np.arange(pminy, pmaxy, self.cellsize)
    pX,pY = np.meshgrid(pxi,pyi)
    pextent = (min(pxi), max(pxi), min(pyi), max(pyi))

    igrid = griddata((ixx, iyy), izz, (iX, iY), method='linear')
    pgrid = griddata((pxx, pyy), pzz, (pX, pY), method='linear')    


# would like to calcualte difference, but this wont work, due to different shapes
changegrid = np.subtract(pgrid, igrid)
```

igrid shape is (181, 130), pgrid shape is (184, 126).

Another important information is these are spatial grids with overlapping spatial extents. If we just broadcast/extend array shapes, would that be enough? I do not want to subtract the grids at wrong x/y locations. So basically like in GIS/Arcmap how we calculate raster difference at each cell at a particular xy cell location.

Comment: Any python/Scipy experts? thanks

Comment: @gene I have provided the shapes here at this post, igrid shape is (181, 130), pgrid shape is (184, 126)